# Crash in Realm due to lack of disk space

Tags: android, realm

I am experiencing some crashes in my Android application when it lacks storage space. The first one to occur is when you write something new to a database, an exception appears that kills the application. For this first one, I use "executeTransaction", should it not handle the exception with "cancelTransaction" without breaking the application?

The second problem is in the log below. After the crash due to lack of space it restarts the application and presents the message that there was apparently a corruption in the database. At the beginning of the application I also execute "compactRealm" method, before calling any instance.

Am I leaving something to do or adopt some bad practice?

`05-16 15:58:17.030 4602-4602/? E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application br.com.application.Application: io.realm.exceptions.RealmFileException: Unable to open a realm at path '/data/data/br.com.application/files/default.realm': Bad Realm file header (#1). (Bad Realm file header (#1)) (/data/data/br.com.application/files/default.realm) in /home/cc/repo/realm/release/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_SharedRealm.cpp line 217 Kind: ACCESS_ERROR.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5248)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:181)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1537)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6134)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)`

Comment: Generally, people have extraordinarily large Realm files if they randomly open local Realm instances on non-looper background threads that they don't ever close. Also if you have multiple processes, compacting on start up can (I think)  start compaction in multiple processes which will corrupt your file.

Comment: The database is less than 1MB in size. The problem occurs when the internal storage space of the device ends, for some reason Realm starts issuing exceptions like: "failed: No space left on device", that break the application and after some starts the error contained in the above log. Should I control this?

Comment: Well...  That seems like a reasonable error to get, when the device runs out of storage!  If there is no space left on the device, then there is no place to put the database data.  I believe we have seen instances in which running out of storage space has corrupted the header.  Will confirm.

Comment: I started using version 3.2.0 of Realm and apparently database corruption has stopped, but still crashes the application. Is there any way to prevent these exceptions for lack of disk space cause the application to crash? Every time I use Realm.getInstance should I check disk space?

Comment: There is a GitHub issue that I believe is related.  It is here: https://github.com/realm/realm-core/issues/1467